# Laravel 9 update foreignkey updated_at

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

Hi I was wondering how to always set the update_at date correct for a parent node in my database when one of its children is updated.
This is my situation :

```js
Parent_table :
  id : 1; updated_at: laraval_date

Child_table :
  id:1;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: laraval_date
  id:2;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: laraval_date
  id:3;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: laraval_date
  id:4;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: laraval_date
```

I would like the parent updated_at to change when one of the children is edited.
For example when some edit is made to child 3.

```js
Parent_table :
  id : 1; updated_at: laraval_date

Child_table :
  id:1;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: laraval_date
  id:2;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: laraval_date
  id:3;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: other_date <= some edit made
  id:4;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: laraval_date
```

This would result in :

```js
Parent_table :
  id : 1; updated_at: other_date <= date is updated as well

Child_table :
  id:1;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: laraval_date
  id:2;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: laraval_date
  id:3;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: other_date 
  id:4;foreign_parent_id:1; updated_at: laraval_date
```

The same should happen when a new child note is added. My solution is rather impracticable and hard to sustain as a child can be edited in many different ways.

```js
Child::where(something is true)->update(something);
Parent::where(something is true)->touch();
```

Does anyone now how to solve this more elegantly. Perhaps with some sort of eloquent hook. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the code mentioned in the post. I haven't tried anything in the form of an eloquent relation as I'm unfamiliar with one that can fix this problem. Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps

Something like:

```
class Child extends Model
{
    protected $touches = ['parent'];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class, "foreign_parent_id");
    }
}
```

Then updating `Child` instance will also update `Parent`